# collectd: Do I need the same plugins on client and server?

Tags: linux, collectd

If I'm using multiple clients that connect to one server to send stats from collectd do I need to enable on server the same plugins that are enabled on client? Or is the data already processed and somehow labeled for use by server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need the plugins on the client(s).

CollectD sends the stats to the (graphite etc.) server with the machine name prefixed to the data. e.g. from my collectd machine: "collectdlocalhostcollectd.cpu-0.cpu-idle"